Landscape table Latex
I am currently doing a literature review and want to add a table in landscape in the appendix of my paper. However, when doing so it overlaps with the previous page making it unreadable.
I am writing the paper in latex. I have tried YT tutorials and searched SO for help yet nothing solved the issue. Would anyone know how to solve this?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{MRE}
\author{}
\date{June 2024}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}


\appendix


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h]

    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
         Author&  Data set size&  Design&  Aim the study&  Results&  Model&  Accuracy& Performance\\
         Roshanzamir, A. et al. (2021)&  1292&  &  Using pre-trained language model to improve AD prediction&  “achieved classification accuracy of 88.08\%, improving the state of the art by 2.48\%”&  &  & \\
         Liu, N et al. (2022) &  156&  &  Implementing a novel algorithm for effective AD diagnosis based on transcripts&  &  &  & \\
         Liu, Z. et al. (2022)&  28&  &  “aimed to investigate the use of RCT’s to develop an AD diagnosis system based on transcription data”&  &  &  & \\
         Yamada, Y. et al. (2022)&  121&  &  Use statistical test in combination with AI to detect AD and DLB from CN&  &  &  & \\
         Mahajan, P. et al. (2021)&  164&  &  Compare different algorithms on a CNN-LSTM architecture to find text embeddings to find AD&  &  &  & \\
         Runde, B. S. et al. (2024)&  1292&  &  Compare different NLP methods to find embeddings to detect AD&  &  &  & \\
         Agbavor, F. \textit{et al. } (2022)&  237&  &  Use GPT-3 to extract text embeddings to detect AD&  &  &  & \\
         Wen, B. et al. (2023)&  1292&  &  Explore the predictive power of PoS tagging for AD using a transformer-based model&  &  &  & \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Included articles}
    \label{tab:my_label
    }

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}


x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/721561/36296
